# Write a number into each cell of a $100\times 100$ tabular

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

1. Is it possible to write either a $0$, a $1$ or a $2$ into each cell of a $100\times 100$ tabular, such that the sum of the 100 numbers  **in each row, column, and (main) diagonal**  is different?
2. Is it possible to write either a $0$, a $1$ or a $2$ into each cell of a $100\times 100$ tabular, such that the sum of the 100 numbers **in each row, column, and one of the (main) diagonals** is different?
3. Is it possible to write either a $0$, a $1$ or a $2$ into each cell of a $100\times 100$ tabular, such that the sum of the 100 numbers **in each row, column** is different?

The first one is not so difficult, just a little Pigeonhole Principle. I am quite sure that the third one is possible. But I don't have any idea about the second one...

Comment: I can at least immediately say, for 2., that the sum on the diagonal must be even, since the number of odd rows and odd columns must be equal.

Comment: Note that having all 201 possible sums means the table (not "tabular") has to have a column (transpose if necessary) that is all $0$s and a column that is all $2$s. And therefore also a column summing to $1$ and a column summing to $199$. None of these can be the diagonal, since that would prevent either a sum of $0$ or of $200$ from occurring at all. It is possible to have rows of sum $3$ or of sum $198$, but only in one way each, which then puts restrictions on the sums in the ramaining columns. But I'm not sure where to go from there.

Comment: I have experimented with $n<<100$. On my limited evidence it seems that the answer to 3 is yes for $n$ even and no for $n$ odd.

Answer (score 0):

The following $100 \times 100$ table solves part 3.
$$ \left[
\begin{array}{ccccc|ccccc}
  2&&\cdots&&2&2&2&\cdots&2&2\\
  2&&\cdots&&2&2&2&\cdots&2&1\\
  &&\cdots&&&&&\cdots&&\\
  2&&\cdots&&2&2&1&\cdots&1&1\\
\hline\
  1&1&\cdots&1&1&0&&\cdots&&0\\
  1&1&\cdots&1&0&0&&\cdots&&0\\
   &&\cdots&&&&&\cdots&&\\
  1&0&\cdots&0&0&0&&\cdots&&0\\
\end{array}
\right] $$
The row sums decrease going from top to bottom from $200$ to $151$ and then $50$ to $1$.
Column sums decrease going from left to right from $150$ to $51$.

**Conjecture**:
  In all the solutions to part 3 either $0$ or $200$ is not one of the sums that appear among the row and column sums.

If the conjecture is true, then the answer to part 2 is no; it is not possible.